# Try Except float but not integer

Tags: python, try-except

So, I've approached an obstacle in a programming exercise. I understand the concept of try except but how can I use a try except handler to only accept a float or decimal and if a whole number or integer is entered, it throws an error message. I know in theory it's not possible but is there a way?

Ideally I want to use a try except block of code as that's the current lesson I am on.

Thanks to all in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using `.is_integer()` on `float`?

```
>>> float(5).is_integer()
True
>>> float(5.12).is_integer()
False
>>>
```

so

```
if float(x).is_integer():
    raise ValueError('Non integers please')
```

Comment: by far the best answer. what are your thoughts on `if float(x) == int(x):` ?

Comment: @karthikr This is great!  I can't believe I've been programming python all these years and didn't know about this.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JohnRuddell sure, but isn't the net effect the same?

Comment: @saulspatz glad it helped

Comment: @karthikr yea i believe so. I dont know what the time complexity is for `is_integer()` just wondering if one is more efficient than the other

Answer (score 1):

```
if type(variable) is not float:
    raise ValueError('Invalid number provided')
```

OR

```
if type(variable) is int:
    raise ValueError('Invalid number provided')
```

OR (to check if whole number):

```
if abs(variable) - floor(abs(variable)) < 1.0e-9:
    raise ValueError('Invalid number provided')
```

Comment: that's still a float. if you mean that you want it to also raise an exception, just add more cases. or, if you just don't want to accept int, use the second statement instead.

Comment: edited again. i do think that this question was originally about raising the exception rather than how to check for whole numbers but oh well :)

Comment: @PeterWood the op's request is that anything besides float/decimal is invalid. the first check does that. op's request `only accept a float or decimal` and he's using python which is the language in question. so whats the issue?

Comment: oh well then just use a float and integer comparison `if float(5) == int(5): raise ValueError()` and yea I didn't see the last part since it was an edit afterwards

Answer (score 1):

There are good answers here, but so far the answers do not use try/except as requested. To use try except, you need try something that will throw an exception if false and then catch the exception.

```
try:
    x / (x - int(x))
except ZeroDivisionError:
    raise Exception("No integers allowed.")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can check the number against types.
# add or remove types from the list
if type(num) in (float, int, Decimal):
  do something
```

Comment: do you mean `if type(num) in (float, int, Decimal):`?